# Php json decode all values in to strings

Tags: php, json

i am trying for like 2 days already do decode a json string, i used json_decode but this wont do it as i wish, i want to decode it in such way that all values are strings after. i am receiving a huge json from a web service and it contains strings, bool, and integers, when i do the decoding in php i want them all to be strings for example, i get a int like 100, after conversion i want it "100", or i get a false, after conversion i want it "false", i wanted to make a script to scan the array of obj that results after using json_decode and convert them in to strings but the company i work for does not like that idea, can someone help me? or give me a hint?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want everything to be in strings?

Comment: All i see is `want` .. Care to post the `JSON` ?

Comment: i cant paste the json because its too big and they wont allow me to, i have to to it so because the app that they are already using is made in such a way that the json has to be converted in string, before the json himself came with all the values already made in strings, but they made and update to the service and all values are what they should be, now i have to find a way to decode it all in string in order to make the app work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [array_walk_recursive][1] to convert every value to string, like this:

```
<?php
$fruits = json_encode ( 
        array (
                'sweet' => array (
                        'a' => 1,
                        'b' => false,
                        'c' => null 
                ),
                'sour' => 'lemon' 
        ) );

$fruits = json_decode ( $fruits, true );

array_walk_recursive ( $fruits, 
        
        function (&$item, $key)
        {
            if ($item === true || $item === false)
            {
                $item = $item ? 'true' : 'false';
            }
            else if ($item === null)
            {
                $item = 'null';
            }
            else
            {
                $item = ( string ) $item;
            }
        } );

var_dump ( $fruits );
```

```
    <?php
    $fruits = json_encode (
            array (
                    'sweet' => array (
                            'a' => 1,
                            'b' => false
                    ),
                    'sour' => 'lemon'
            ) );
    
    $fruits = json_decode ( $fruits, true );
    
    function convertToString(&$item, $key)
    {
        if ($item === true || $item === false)
        {
            $item = $item ? 'true' : 'false';
        }
        else
        {
            $item =  ( string ) $item;
        }
    }
    
    array_walk_recursive ( $fruits, 'convertToString' );
    
    var_dump ( $fruits );
```


  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: I`m sorry i forgot to mention that after using json decode it results a multidimensional array of objects

Comment: That why I use json_decode ($json, true ), the "true" param will make sure the return result is just Array, not Object

Comment: Thank you ! it helped me a lot, using this i managed to convert also the values that were in objects, Thanks a lot

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to used a lambda for `array_walk_recursive()` and to do `$item = (string) $item;` instead of `$item = '' . $item;`?

Comment: You're right, @user555, (string) is better. lambda is fine if php version >=5.3

Comment: @ZetCoby, I edit the answer according to user555's comment. Also add "null" condition.

Comment: thank you again, i`m just in my first year of a web programmer and this is like a lesson for me, learned a lot from this.

Comment: this wont help for phone numbers (eg 0123456789 will become "123456789") which isn't what we want

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get strings with json_decode. You should either find some json library with that ability or make a custom parser.

Another way is to traverse the resulted array and update the values. E.g.

```
$arr = array(1=>true, 2=>false, 5=>5, 4 =>null, 3=>array(1=>"true", 2=>false));
var_dump($arr);
function update_value(&$item,$key) {
    if ($item === null) $item = "null";
    elseif ($item === false) $item = "false";
    elseif ($item === true) $item = "true";
    else $item.="";
    // ... so on
}
array_walk_recursive($arr,'update_value');
var_dump($arr);
```